# VBA Loop Within a Loop Where the Second Loop Always Starts at 1

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code below that loops through all slides in a PPT presentation. If the slides fall under one of the sections and are not hidden, it will save them with an appropriate name. I am trying to get the number after the saved name (i.e. TEST#) to always start over at 1 for each section. So if there are five slides within the IDSS section, which starts at slide 5, then they would be saved: IDSS1, IDSS2, etc. The way I have it below just saves it with the current slide number. Thanks for any help you can provide!

***Edit to Provide More Clearity***

I have many different slides in this PPT presentation, all of which are located within a particular named section. For this example, assume there are 6 total slides. Slides 1-3 are in the section named "TEST" and slide 3 is hidden. Slides 4-6 are in the section "IDSS" and none are hidden. I need the code to loop through all the slides, figure out which ones are in the "TEST" section and name them "TEST1" and "TEST2" (the third slide is skipped since it is hidden). Then it moves on to the section "IDSS" and saves the slides as "IDSS1", IDSS2", and "IDSS3". It's the number after the name I can't get to restart at 1 for each section. Hope this makes it more clear.

```
Dim sld As Slide

TestSection = SectionIndexOf("Test") 'Name of a section is in the quotes.

IDSSslides = SectionIndexOf("IDSS")

i = 1
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If sld.sectionIndex = TestSection And ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "TEST" & i & ".png", "PNG"
    ElseIf sld.sectionIndex = IDSSslides And ActivePresentation.Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "IDSS" & i & ".png", "PNG"
    End If
i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: So are you asking how to find out what `filenamepng` should ***be***, or is that defined and given a value elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry, that is defined and given a value elsewhere. I just need the variable currently labeled `i` after the name in quotes (i.e. "TEST" and "IDSS") to start at one for each section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, but I think that this is what you need, try it and let me know

```
    Dim sld As Slide

TestSection = SectionIndexOf("Test") 'Name of a section is in the quotes.

IDSSslides = SectionIndexOf("IDSS")

dim i as integer 'Counter for TEST 
dim j as integer'Counter for IDSS 

i = 1 
j=1

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If sld.sectionIndex = TestSection And sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
        sld.Export filenamepng & "TEST" & i & ".png", "PNG"
        i=i+1
    ElseIf sld.sectionIndex = IDSSslides And sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
        sld.Export filenamepng & "IDSS" & j & ".png", "PNG"
        j=j+1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That does not work. In the first "section" in my presentation (named "Test") there are three slides with the 3rd one hidden. The second section (named "IDSS") has 3 slides and they are slides 4, 5, and 6. This codes saves the first 2 slides (not the 3rd since it is hidden) twice. Once as TEST1 and TEST2, the other as IDSS1 and IDSS2. What I want the code to do is save the first 2 slides as TEST1 and TEST2. Then save slides 4-6, which are in the IDSS section, as IDSS1, IDSS2, and IDSS3. Hope that clears it up a bit. Thanks!

Comment: instead of `ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Export filenamepng & "IDSS" & j & ".png", "PNG"` make it `sld.Export filenamepng & "IDSS" & j & ".png", "PNG"` and similar for TEST section

Comment: @hunter21188 you have to be more clear in your question to get a clear answer, I focused on showing you how to make the correct numbers, but now your asking about your conditions, update your question to be able to help. I will adapt my answer based on ahmed AH answer if he understood what you mean

Comment: @AhmedAU Very close! It correctly saves slides 4 and 5 as IDSS1 and IDSS2, however it is ending the loop after 2 and not making it to slide 6. This has something to do with the fact there are only two unhidden slides in the TEST section. If I unhide that slide it makes it the whole way through.

Comment: @JustGreat Yes, I did. It is very close, just stopping after the second time through, so it never makes it to slide 6. See my comment above for more info. I also updated my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @hunter21188 Just saw it, tell me, can you confirm that this code is saving all your visible slides and not saving your hidden one ? is this what you mean ?

Comment: @ JustGreat  may also  try change `ActivePresentation.Slides(j).SlideShowTransition.Hidden`  to `sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden`

Comment: @JustGreat @AhmedAU Ah, I had to make both parts of the `If` statement `sld.` and that solved it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @hunter21188 I will correct it right above and please tagg it as resolved.

Comment: @JustGreat Perfect. Will do. Thanks again!

Comment: @hunter21188 glad to know that your problem is solved